# Get the Model of a OneToOne

Tags: django, metadata, one-to-one

I need to get the Model of a OneToOne related model:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    target = models.OneToOneField(
        ModelA, 
        related_name="model_a", 
    ...)
```

When I use an instance of ModelB to get the class of its target field with:

```
 modelb_instance.model_a._meta.model
```

I get an error:

```
ForwardOneToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

I am aware that this cannot be done on OneToOne attribute, but I am not sure how to retrieve ModelA model name.
Any help would be appreciated

As @Willem suggested working though the Options of a ModelB did the job:
`modelb_instance._meta.get_field('target').related_model`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with:

```
ModelB.target.field.related_model
```

or for a `modelb_instance`:

```
type(modelb_instance).target.field.related_model
```

or we can work through the `Options` of `ModelB` with:

```
modelb_instance._meta.get_field('target').related_model
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, working though the **Options**  of a ModelB works!